# Dynamodb can't create tables

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am testing out AWS DynamoDB on my local, but I can't create tables with and global indexes.

I receive the following output and I am unsure why. I think I am adding a hash key to the tables and indexes, so I am unsure why it is complaining?

```
Issuing CreateTable request for Users
Waiting for Users to be created...this may take a while...
Issuing CreateTable request for Contacts
CreateTable request failed for Contacts
No Hash Key specified in schema.  All Dynamo DB tables must have exactly one hash key (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: b2c826df-a6e6-4bc5-af60-ff6b6c3a0065)
Issuing CreateTable request for Messages
CreateTable request failed for Messages
No Hash Key specified in schema.  All Dynamo DB tables must have exactly one hash key (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 2117d767-f87f-4147-bfee-cafce6cf0ad8)
```

This is my code (I am creating 3 tables, 2 with global indexes):

```
public class Main{

    AmazonDynamoDBClient client;
    static DynamoDB dynamoDB;

    static String users = "Users";
    static String contacts = "Contacts";
    static String messages = "Messages";


    public Main() throws Exception {

        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000");
        dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);


        try {

            deleteTable(users);
            deleteTable(contacts);
            deleteTable(messages);

            createTable(users, 10L, 5L, "un", "S");
            createTable(contacts, 10L, 5L, "to", "S");
            createTable(messages, 10L, 5L, "fr", "S", "cr", "S");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Program failed:");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Success.");


    private static void deleteTable(String tableName) {
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
        try {
            System.out.println("Issuing DeleteTable request for " + tableName);
            table.delete();
            System.out.println("Waiting for " + tableName
                    + " to be deleted...this may take a while...");
            table.waitForDelete();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("DeleteTable request failed for " + tableName);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private static void createTable(
            String tableName, long readCapacityUnits, long writeCapacityUnits,
            String hashKeyName, String hashKeyType) {

        createTable(tableName, readCapacityUnits, writeCapacityUnits,
                hashKeyName, hashKeyType, null, null);
    }

    private static void createTable(
            String tableName, long readCapacityUnits, long writeCapacityUnits,
            String hashKeyName, String hashKeyType,
            String rangeKeyName, String rangeKeyType) {

        try {

            ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> keySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();
            keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                    .withAttributeName(hashKeyName)
                    .withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));

            ArrayList<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = new ArrayList<AttributeDefinition>();
            attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition()
                    .withAttributeName(hashKeyName)
                    .withAttributeType(hashKeyType));

            if (rangeKeyName != null) {
                keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName(rangeKeyName)
                        .withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE));
                attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition()
                        .withAttributeName(rangeKeyName)
                        .withAttributeType(rangeKeyType));
            }

            CreateTableRequest request = new CreateTableRequest()
                    .withTableName(tableName)
                    .withKeySchema(keySchema)
                    .withProvisionedThroughput( new ProvisionedThroughput()
                            .withReadCapacityUnits(readCapacityUnits)
                            .withWriteCapacityUnits(writeCapacityUnits));



            if(contacts.equals(tableName)){

                // PrecipIndex
                GlobalSecondaryIndex contactsFromIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndex()
                        .withIndexName("ContactsFromIndex")
                        .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput()
                                .withReadCapacityUnits((long) 10)
                                .withWriteCapacityUnits((long) 5))
                        .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.KEYS_ONLY));

                ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> indexKeySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();

                indexKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName("fr")
                        .withKeyType("S"));
                indexKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName("st")
                        .withKeyType("N"));

                contactsFromIndex.setKeySchema(indexKeySchema);
                request.withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(contactsFromIndex);

            }


            if(messages.equals(tableName)){

                // PrecipIndex
                GlobalSecondaryIndex messagesFromIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndex()
                        .withIndexName("messagesFromIndex")
                        .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput()
                                .withReadCapacityUnits((long) 10)
                                .withWriteCapacityUnits((long) 5))
                        .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.INCLUDE)
                                .withNonKeyAttributes("mg"));

                ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> indexKeySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();

                indexKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName("to")
                        .withKeyType("S"));
                indexKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName("cr")
                        .withKeyType("N"));

                messagesFromIndex.setKeySchema(indexKeySchema);
                request.withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(messagesFromIndex);

            }


            request.setAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions);

            System.out.println("Issuing CreateTable request for " + tableName);
            Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(request);
            System.out.println("Waiting for " + tableName
                    + " to be created...this may take a while...");
            table.waitForActive();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("CreateTable request failed for " + tableName);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATED :** Error message 'Cannot have two attributes with the same name' with new code:

```
        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000");
        dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);


        try {

            deleteTable(users);
            deleteTable(contacts);
            deleteTable(messages);

            createTable(users, 10L, 5L, "un", "S");
            createTable(contacts, 10L, 5L, "to", "S");
            createTable(messages, 10L, 5L, "fr", "S", "cr", "S");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Program failed:");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Success.");


    private static void deleteTable(String tableName) {
        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
        try {
            System.out.println("Issuing DeleteTable request for " + tableName);
            table.delete();
            System.out.println("Waiting for " + tableName
                    + " to be deleted...this may take a while...");
            table.waitForDelete();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("DeleteTable request failed for " + tableName);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private static void createTable(
            String tableName, long readCapacityUnits, long writeCapacityUnits,
            String hashKeyName, String hashKeyType) {

        createTable(tableName, readCapacityUnits, writeCapacityUnits,
                hashKeyName, hashKeyType, null, null);
    }

    private static void createTable(
            String tableName, long readCapacityUnits, long writeCapacityUnits,
            String hashKeyName, String hashKeyType,
            String rangeKeyName, String rangeKeyType) {

        try {

            ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> keySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();
            keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                    .withAttributeName(hashKeyName)
                    .withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));

            ArrayList<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = new ArrayList<AttributeDefinition>();
            attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition()
                    .withAttributeName(hashKeyName)
                    .withAttributeType(hashKeyType));

            if (rangeKeyName != null) {
                keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName(rangeKeyName)
                        .withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE));
                attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition()
                        .withAttributeName(rangeKeyName)
                        .withAttributeType(rangeKeyType));
            }

            CreateTableRequest request = new CreateTableRequest()
                    .withTableName(tableName)
                    .withKeySchema(keySchema)
                    .withProvisionedThroughput( new ProvisionedThroughput()
                            .withReadCapacityUnits(readCapacityUnits)
                            .withWriteCapacityUnits(writeCapacityUnits));



            if(contacts.equals(tableName)){
 attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("fr").withAttributeType("S"));
                     attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("st").withAttributeType("S"));
                // PrecipIndex
                GlobalSecondaryIndex contactsFromIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndex()
                        .withIndexName("ContactsFromIndex")
                        .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput()
                                .withReadCapacityUnits((long) 10)
                                .withWriteCapacityUnits((long) 5))
                        .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.KEYS_ONLY));

                ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> indexKeySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();

                indexKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName("fr")
                        .withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));
                indexKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName("st")
                        .withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE));

                contactsFromIndex.setKeySchema(indexKeySchema);
                request.withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(contactsFromIndex);

            }


            if(messages.equals(tableName)){
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("to").withAttributeType("S"));
                    attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("cr").withAttributeType("N"));

                // PrecipIndex
                GlobalSecondaryIndex messagesFromIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndex()
                        .withIndexName("messagesFromIndex")
                        .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput()
                                .withReadCapacityUnits((long) 10)
                                .withWriteCapacityUnits((long) 5))
                        .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.INCLUDE)
                                .withNonKeyAttributes("mg"));

                ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> indexKeySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();

                indexKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName("to")
                        .withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));
                indexKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
                        .withAttributeName("cr")
                        .withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE));

                messagesFromIndex.setKeySchema(indexKeySchema);
                request.withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(messagesFromIndex);

            }


            request.setAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions);

            System.out.println("Issuing CreateTable request for " + tableName);
            Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(request);
            System.out.println("Waiting for " + tableName
                    + " to be created...this may take a while...");
            table.waitForActive();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("CreateTable request failed for " + tableName);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code construct to add GSI based on the table name,

```
if(contacts.equals(tableName)){
   ...
   .withKeyType("S"));
   .withKeyType("N"));
   ...
}
```

and

```
if(messages.equals(tableName)){
   ...
   .withKeyType("S"));
   .withKeyType("N"));
   ...
}
```

The API `withKeyType(...)` takes in the Key Type, e.g. Hash | Range, not the data type.

**Correct Example**:

```
.withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have added the hash and range key types to both, but now get an error saying "Global Secondary Index hash key not specified in Attribute Definitons.Type unknown."

Comment: The exception is saying it couldn't determine the data type of the hash key specified by the GSI. In this case, you need to include in your attributeDefinitions array list the GSI Hash Key.

Comment: Example: attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("to").withAttributeType("S"));

Comment: Doesn't my attributesDefenitions arraylist already add the key and type from the passed in parameters of the method 'create table'?

Comment: No, from the codes above, I can see that only the table's hash and/or Range key is added to attributeDefinitions. You are still missing the GSI's Hash and/or Range keys. I.e, "fr", "to", "at", "to" depending on the table.

Comment: Inside the Contact if statement I added on the first line:                 attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("fr").withAttributeType("S"));. For messages I added: attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("to").withAttributeType("S"));
               attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("cr").withAttributeType("N"));
               attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("mg").withAttributeType("S")); . It still gives the error

Comment: For contact table, you need "fr" and "st", for message, "to" and "cr".

Comment: The error message went away, but now there is a new one:  'Cannot have two attributes with the same name' . I have updated my question with my new code

Comment: For message table, "cr" is being added to attributeDefinitions list twice, once for the table, once for the GSI. You should check and add only if it does not exist in the list.

Comment: Np! Have fun with DynamoDb Java API.